# How do I store users in my SQLEXPRESS database in C# MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-express

I am just learning MVC and I wanted to store my data in SQLEXPRESS instead of the MDF file that's provided.

I went online and learned that I was supposed to change Web.config, so I commented out and replaced the connection string like so:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <!--<add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=BuySellDB"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

I was hoping that `System.Security.Membership` would automatically create a new database and table to hold my information, but it doesn't -- instead, it just barfs because it can't find a database there. How do I configure it to create a new database and table if none exists?

**Edit:** I was watching tutorial videos on [asp.net/mvc](http://asp.net/mvc)  and I saw how `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` can be used to auto-create or re-create the necessary database and schema. I was hoping there was some way to include the `aspnet_*` tables in that....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create the database by yourself using the command promt.

Start that command promt and execute "aspnet_regsql". A Wizard will start 
and help you create the database.

Here is nice sample => 
http://www.ezineasp.net/post/How-to-Create-Aspnetdb.aspx

If you want to give the project away. Think about

- create the database as i told
- create a sql script from that
- build the database using SqlClient in your application on first startup

You could check if the database exists in the global.asax "Application_Start" Method

```
protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
 //... check if your database already exists, if not DO IT ;)
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to make MVC automatically do this if it doesn't exist? I want to share this project with others using Git, and I don't want to make them go through this if it's possible to avoid it...

Comment: @Robert - no, the user-mode DB *is* the only "automatic" way.

Comment: If you want to give the project away. Think about => create the database as i told => create a sql script from that => build the database using SqlClient in your application on first startup.

Comment: @dknaack Thank you, that tutorial worked perfectly for me. Unfortunately I'm not sure how to do "application on first startup". How does my application know the first time it's turned on in a new environment?

Comment: You could check if the database exists in the global.asax "Application_Start" Method.

Answer (score 2):

In the scenario that you want - your database IS a valid sql express MDF file.

This *is* usually the best way to share the solution otherwise you are going to have to worry about database config, setting up the db, which server, etc. If you still want to do that you'll want to right click on your data connection in the server explorer in visual studio and publish the database and generate scripts if you have anything custom otherwise use aspnet_regsql.

However I still strongly suggest if you are sharing this application you keep it in the app_Data folder and let other users choose if they want it to run elsewhere. They can publish it as they see fit using the same method.

Comment: Okay, I was just watching the tutorial videos on asp.net/mvc and they talk about how to auto-create the DB and Schema for Models in my MVC application using `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`. I can't use that for user data, though?

Comment: No ;) Thats another thing. Looks like you saw a video about EntityFramework CodeFirst development.

Comment: That's exactly what I saw. Too bad it's not integrated, that would be swell :-) Unfortunately I can't just use the MDF file even though that would be easier, because I am working in a group and they are adamant about using SqlServer...

Comment: but - an MDF file is SQL server. You can take that mdf file and simply attach it in sql server. So - it can use built in sql express app_data. If you want sql server, move the mdf file. OR in the case you mentioned above you can actually create the db on the server and script the data and just execute the script to populate. There are many ways to accomplish this, but yes - you technically could do this with the entity framework code first and scripting your data. I recall asking one of the EF team members about this